# What's the equivalent of Access VBA Application.CodeContextObject in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

http://datagnostics.com/dtips/whatobject.html

> the CodeContextObject property returns
>   a reference to the object from which
>   the currently executing macro or VBA
>   procedure was called. **This may or
>   may not be the active object.**

What's the equivalent in C# or VB.NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in C# or VB.NET that will give you a method's calling *object*, but you can get the calling *method* like this:

```
var callingMethod = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
```

Comment: Does it mean there's no way I can call another method of that object using reflection ?

Comment: You can get the object's type but not the object, i.e., you can't use that instance to call any of its other methods.

Comment: Oh my that sucks, why did they prevent this :(